# Sorting one table result by highest count of items from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have table Products where I store my products and another table Votes which cointains user votes for that products.

```
Product:
ID
Name
Price
etc..

Votes:
ID
ProductID
IpAdress
DateTimeCreated
```

How would I get most voted products in last 24 hours in linq to sql? I'm really not that good with L2S to figure it on my own.

This is closest I got so far, this snippet should get last 10 voted, but I need top voted in last 24h:

```
 var last10Voted = (from vote in context.Votes join product in 
 context.Products on vote.ProductID equals
 product.ID orderby vote.DateTimeCreated select product).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var topVotedProducts = 
    Votes.Where(v => v.DateTimeCreated > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24))
        .GroupBy(v => v.ProductID)
        .Join(Products, g => g.Key, p => p.ID, (g,p) => new { cnt = g.Count(), prod = p.Name })
        .OrderByDescending(result => result.cnt);
```

Product:
ID
Name
Price
etc..

Votes:
ID
ProductID
IpAdress
DateTimeCreated

Answer (score 2):

```
var last10Voted =
  ( 
    from product in context.Products
    let votes = context.Votes
                       .Where(v=>v.ProductID == product.ID 
                                && v.DateTimeCreated >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24))
    orderby votes.Count() descending
    select product
 ).Take(10);
```

Comment: There is no need to use Where.You can apply the filter directly within a Count extension method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mostVoted =
    from product in context.Products
    let votes = context.Votes.Count(vote => vote.ProductID == product.ID && (DateTime.Now - vote.DateTimeCreated).TotalHours <= 24)
    orderby votes descending
    select product;

var top10 = mostVoted.Take(10);
```

Comment: this is not "last 10" and there can be multiple votes for the same product